# MySQL SELECT statement with two WHERE clauses

Tags: php, mysql

**Problem**: How do I concatenate two MySQL tables using two different columns?

I have two MySQL Tables.

```
**DescriptionTable**. Fields: {filename, ID}.
**ResultsTable**. Fields: {query_id, media_id}. Both fields reference the ID field in the DescriptionTable.
```

A "match" links a query_id to a specified media_id, and an entry is added into ResultsTable.

I would like it so that I can do a SELECT query that retrieves the following:

```
[filename (query_id), filename (media_id)]
```

**What I Have Tried**:

```
SELECT a.filename
FROM DescriptionTable a, ResultsTable b
WHERE a.id = b.query_id
```

... but this only gives me the `query_id`'s filename and not both of the filenames associated with `query_id` and `media_id`. How can I incorporate both in one SELECT command?

Comment: unions (same # of columns and types) .... and `explicit joins` ... change the old style joins in a where clause in favor of explicit joins

Comment: in your select .... select a.id,a.col2,b.col1,b.media_id etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join `DescriptionTable` to `ResultsTable` twice, once on `query_id` and once on `media_id`.

```
SELECT dq.filename as query_filename, dm.filename as media_filename
FROM ResultsTable r
INNER JOIN DescriptionTable dq ON r.query_id = dq.ID
INNER JOIN DescriptionTable dm on r.media_id = dm.ID
```

This should return rows with filenames for both `query_id` and `media_id` that correspond to the id pairs in the rows of `ResultsTable`.